# Adding group of rows to ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I'd like to add a group of lines to a list and have the following erroneous code:

```
StatusBox.Items.Insert(0, "-".PadRight(this.StatusBox.Width,'-'));
StatusBox.Items.Insert(0, "Total search results: 0");
StatusBox.Items.Insert(0, "Searching database: " + Dropdown1Selection.SelectedItem.ToString());
StatusBox.Items.Insert(0, "Searching server: " + Dropdown2Selection.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

`StatusBox` is of type ListBox. The code above was a result of how I was seeing the desired result when it was a SINGLE line of text being added. But now that it's a group of rows, it looks something like:

[image]

Comment: So, you want to add a gruop of lines within one line?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid , not within one line, but grouped together. So, "Searching database:" "Searching server:" and "Total search results" would be one group of lines, and then move to the next group of the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties for the ListBox, I had to change the "Sorted" property to False:

[image]